# Find numbers divisible by 3 in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I am doing this for pure fun since I'm exploring into ArrayLists. I know how to use the modulus operator to check if it's divisible by 3. But, have know clue on how to use it with an arrayList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Print out only a set of numbers divisible by 3 from an array.

    ArrayList<Integer> division = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Add a set of numbers.
    Division.add(10);
    Division.add(3);
    Division.add(34);
    Division.add(36);
    Division.add(435);
    Division.add(457);
    Division.add(223);
    Division.add(45);
    Division.add(4353);
    Division.add(99);


    //How can I fix the logic below?
    if(Division.get() % 3 == 0)

}
```

}

Comment: You should not upper case the first letter in variables, in Java the naming convention is to upper case it in class names and lower case it in variable names, as well as method names.

Answer (score 6):

You need to loop over the items in your list, for example, using the enhanced for loop syntax:

```
for (int i : Division) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i + " is divisible by 3");
    }
}
```

Note:

- You should apply the java naming conventions. In particular, variable names start in lower case (apart from constants): `Division` => `division`.
- And your `division` object is really a list of numbers, so `numbers` would probably be a better name.

More info about lists in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Comment: I was so close to this -__-. Thanks. Just too many loops out there and just not sure when to use them. Hopefully, Trial and Error will teach.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(Integer number: division){
  if(number % 3 == 0){
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

As a Java naming convention: Only classes start with an upper case. Variables start with a lower case, so this is better: `ArrayList<Integer> division = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Answer (score 5):

alternatively, you can also use a "normal" for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Division.size(); i++)
     {
       if(Division.get(i) % 3 == 0)
       {
        System.out.println(Division.get(i));
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should declare your variable starting with lowercase alphabet or underscore..

Second you need to iterate over your ArrayList to fetch it's element, and your ArrayList should be of `Wrapper Type` Integer not of `Primitive type` int..

```
ArrayList<Integer> division = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Initialize your arraylist here
for (Integer i : division) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number : " + i + "is divisible by 3");
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [blog](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-loop-arraylist-in-java-code.html).. It has wide examples covering how to iterate over `List`..